# javascript date как взять дату предыдущего дня?

Tags: javascript, дата

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: хочу взять дату предыдущего дня, но когда дата - это первый день в году, то работа даты `javascript` некорректная.

Вот пример кода:

Здесь мне должен возвратить такой результат `day - 31, month - 11 (месяцы из даты начинаются с 0 до 11) и year - 2016`, но мой результат в примере вот такой `day - 31, month - 0, year - 217`

```js
var d = new Date(2017, 1, 1);
    
d = new Date(d.getTime() - 86400000);
var from_day = d.getDate();
console.log(d.getTime());
console.log(from_day);
console.log(d.getMonth());
console.log(d.getFullYear());
```

Comment: Так Вы дату изначально на 1 февраля устанавливаете.

Comment: @Oleg что самое смешное, автор сам же в вопросе это написал))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ага, тоже нахожу забавным. Бывает заработаешься.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо, вот час уже потратил на тупую ошибку))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы установили дату на 1 февраля.

```js
var d = new Date(2017, 0, 1);
    
d = new Date(d.getTime() - 86400000);
var from_day = d.getDate();
console.log(d.getTime());
console.log(from_day);
console.log(d.getMonth());
console.log(d.getFullYear());
```

Поменял месяц на 0 и все.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с вычитанием 24 часов (или 86400000 мс.) может не всегда/не везде корректно работать. К примеру в дни когда происходит переход с летнего времени на стандартное в сутках будет 25 часов.

Если нужно получать предыдущий календарный день то корректнее будет делать так:

```
var d = new Date(2017, 1, 1); //1 февраля 2017
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1); //d изменится на 31 января 2017
```

Функция `setDate` устанавливает день текущего месяца даты, при этом она учитывает расовой пояс пользователя (и переходы данного часового пояса). При этом если день месяца выходит за количество дней в данном месяца, то будет изменён месяц. Так, если на вход `setDate` передать 0 то месяц изменится на предыдущий, а день будет равен последнему дню предыдущего месяца. Если передать 29 то месяц изменится на следующий (т.к. в феврале 2017 только 28 дней).

```
var d = new Date(2017, 0, 1); //1 января 2017
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1); // d изменится на 31 декабря 2016
```